# Xamarin HybridWebView calling JS function from C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I'm trying to get a HybridWebView where JS and C# code can communicate with each other. I followed [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) and it works fine to call C# code from JS. However i need the other way around too, which is not guided in the tutorial mentioned. 
This is how far i got:

In my HybridWebView controll i added the following lines:

```
public event EventHandler CallJavascript;

public void InvokeJS()
{
    if(CallJavascript != null)
    {
        CallJavascript(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In my custom renderer i added the CallJavascript method and it in the `OnElementChanged()` method

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
            SetNativeControl(webView);


        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();

            e.OldElement.CallJavascript += OnElementCallJavascript;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{Element.Uri}");
            e.NewElement.CallJavascript += OnElementCallJavascript;
        }
    }


private void OnElementCallJavascript(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        webView.EvaluateJavascript("javascript:increaseCount();", null);
    });
}
```

however, the webview i'm getting in my OnElementCallJavascript is not the WebView i'm calling the method from, therefore no javascript is evaluated. Anyone got a clue how i can achieve this?

Comment: You can use the plugin FormsWebView or checkout the implementation procedure in it's github repository. Repo: https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was creating a new `Android.WebKit.WebView`.
Using it like this solved the problem:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     Control.EvaluateJavascript("javascript:increaseCount();", null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just use something like this instead/directly?

```
e.NewElement.CallJavascript  += (sender, args) =>
{                    
    Control.EvaluateJavascript("javascript:increaseCount();", null);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HybridWebView in Xamarin.Forms define a Bindable Layout and Action:

```
 public class HybridWebView : WebView
{
    Action<string> action;
    public static BindableProperty EvaluateJavascriptProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EvaluateJavascript), typeof(Func<string, Task<string>>), typeof(HybridWebView), null, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public Func<string, Task<string>> EvaluateJavascript
    {
        get { return (Func<string, Task<string>>)GetValue(EvaluateJavascriptProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EvaluateJavascriptProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string key)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(key);
    }
}
```

Call EvaluateJavacript in your Page:

```
await webview.EvaluateJavascript("javascript:increaseCount();");
```

In your Renderer:

```
private HybridWebView xfWebView;
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
            SetNativeControl(webView);


        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();

            e.OldElement.CallJavascript += OnElementCallJavascript;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            xfWebView = e.NewElement;
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            if (xfWebView != null)
                {
                    xfWebView.EvaluateJavascript = async (js) =>
                    {
                        var reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                        var response = string.Empty;
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            Control?.EvaluateJavascript(js, new JavascriptCallback((r) => { response = r; reset.Set(); }));
                        });
                        await Task.Run(() => { reset.WaitOne(); });
                        return response;
                    };
                }
         Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{Element.Uri}");
        }
}
```